# Typescript code help to evaluate column H (EffDate) cell value not equal to today's date minus 1 day, true delete row in Excel sheet

Tags: typescript, excel-online

I want to delete all rows that don't meet the condition date.now() -1 day.  I have multiple date columns but only want to evaluate column H (Column #7).

I tried using various code examples but could not get any of them to work.

Comment: add your code what you ahve tried, and we can improve it further as per your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.